# Python: Are there any libraries with all the unicode characters similar to the string library for ascii characters?

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

In python, the string library has methods like string.ascii_letters. Is there anything similar for Unicode characters or symbols? I haven't been able to find anything myself.

I appreciate any help! Fairly new to this type of thing so apologies if this question is dumb.

Comment: Using [the `unicodedata` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) you could loop through all the possible unicode code points and generate your own list.

Comment: Please provide representative code and data for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#chr) built-in function.

> Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is the integer i. For example, chr(97) returns the string 'a', while chr(8364) returns the string '€'. The valid range for the argument is from 0 through 1,114,111 (0x10FFFF in base 16). ValueError will be raised if i is outside that range.

So you can do something like this to get a result similar to `string.ascii_letters`:

```
''.join(map(chr, range(1114112)))
```

Instead, if you just want a list:

```
list(map(chr, range(1114112)))
```

Comment: this helps a lot, thanks!

Comment: Not everything in that range will be a valid Unicode character.

Comment: Or a "letter" for that matter, but you could filter the list on `unicodedata.category()`